# There are 8 of them! I want their heads!

Tags: riddle, pattern, enigmatic-puzzle, steganography

These lines can't make any sense. Even the numbering is not correct. What are they hiding?

> .1. I'm the largest of us all.
>   .3. 'Bring me a pen!' lovably said in anger. 'Why is it so hopeful when scouts tracing Craig study crude need of every awkward try? E-v-e-r-y!'.
>   .4. Flying Smoke known also as Awry Knife flew over realm of my corrosion. Why, you ask? Claim but a rust and every extort is you.
>   .5. What in clams is made sole? Claming done desperately can blow your inner zeal. Make directed call. Even exiled clammers impede utter smiles. You, umhumble clam, arised.
>   .0.
>   .4. 'Can I get my dry lemon? You heard me! Bride says you took five resting eels. One today.'
>   .5. Twilight among savage crimson peppers. Speed her up or we'll be late. We thank for grinding he added to small pepper here.
>   .6. When silly humorous answer gains too much of votedowns, is it a fair training of 'go answer some riddle awarding high'? Is this going through trial abandoning the right address?
>   .1. I'm largest of all who stand the ground.

Comment: Ok, So what we have to do?? Arrange the lines such that they make sense??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, This is definitely the answer now!  The first step is to decode the clues.  Here's how it works:

> Where the number at the beginning of each line is *n*, take every *n*'th letter (ignoring puctuation) to get the translated clue.  Where *n* = 1, the translation makes no change from the original.

.1. I'm the largest of us all.

> I'm the largest of us all. (whale, largest animal)

.3. 'Bring me a pen!' lovably said in anger. 'Why is it so hopeful when scouts tracing Craig study crude need of every awkward try? E-v-e-r-y!'.

> im playing With electriCity underwatEr  (eel)

.4. Flying Smoke known also as Awry Knife flew over realm of my corrosion. Why, you ask? Claim but a rust and every extort is you.

> im known for my royal bravery  (Lion, king of beasts)

.5. What in clams is made sole? Claming done desperately can blow your inner zeal. Make directed call. Even exiled clammers impede utter smiles. You, umhumble clam, arised.

> im almost a wizard Except mY head. (lizard)

.0.

> ?

.4. 'Can I get my dry lemon? You heard me! Bride says you took five resting eels. One today.'

> Im your Best friend (dog)

.5. Twilight among savage crimson peppers. Speed her up or we'll be late. We thank for grinding he added to small pepper here.

> i'm a copper bearded ape (orangutan)

.6. When silly humorous answer gains too much of votedowns, is it a fair training of 'go answer some riddle awarding high'? Is this going through trial abandoning the right address?

> i'm a good singer a nIght bird (nightingale)

.1. I'm largest of all who stand the ground.

> I'm largest of all who stand the ground. (elephant, largest land animal)

Finally:

> WELL DONE! (first letter or "head" of each animal's name)

Comment: Well done indeed, but you should explain how you used the numbers to extract the questions.

Comment: The "0" line was meant to indicate a whitespace.